# Refresh page, sessionStorage value lost

Tags: javascript, refresh, sessionstorage

In javascript, I want to use sessionStorage, and make sure that after refreshing page, don't lost page data.

What I do is, press one button, do webservice call, show msg on page.

```
var str;
http.getDataFromServer(function(data){
    str = data.msg; // msg is a string, could be "Hello"
    sessionStorage.setItem("msg", str);
})
```

then I refresh the page, and execute

```
sessionStorage.getItem('msg');
```

but what I got is a string "null". I think the value I stored is a reference, after refreshing, the str is no longer existed, so the value is lost.

Is there a method that I only stored the str content instead of the reference?

Comment: Does the same thing happen on different browsers?

Comment: `I think the value I stored is a reference` - no, because as you comment in the code `msg is a string`

Comment: same thing if you do sessionStorage['msg'] = str; ?

Comment: what happens if you run `sessionStorage.getItem('msg');` in the console BEFORE the refresh, but after the first piece of code is executed,

Comment: `a string "null"` ... that means you've stored a string 'null' ... are you sure it's a string 'null' or is it a `null`? `typeof sessionStorage.getItem('msg');` in the console will tell you

Comment: @JaromandaX Before I refresh the page, I can get the item correctly.

Comment: what browser, have you tried other browsers